# I am trying to write data.table to schema present in SQL server Express. I am using the package 'RODBC' and the functions- 'dbWriteTable' &'sqlSave'

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, odbc

How to write data.table to the SQL server/ SQL Server Express using `odbc` package at once and not line by line?

I am able to use `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` command using R, however it seems to write line by line? Is there any optimized way to do this?

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                  Driver = "SQL Server", 
                  Server = "DE-SS14614-01\\SQLEXPRESS", 
                  Database = "testdb", 
                  Trusted_Connection = "True")

dt <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM testdb.dbo.Site")

dt1 <- data.table("Site_Id" = c(1:5), "Name"=  c('S', 'M', 'k', 'F', 'T'), "Type" = c(""), "Region" = c('USA'))

dbWriteTable(con, "testdb.dbo.Site", dt1, overwrite = TRUE,  row.names = FALSE)

sqlSave(con, dt1, "testdb.dbo.Site", rownames = F)

## sqlSave & dbWriteTable does not seem to work
```

Errors:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>       unable to find an inherited method for function 'dbWriteTable' for 
>       signature ‘"RODBC", "character", "data.table"
>
> Error in sqlSave(conn, as.data.frame(dt1), "testdb.dbo.Site", 
>       rownames = 'F,  : 
>       42S01 2714 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]There 
>       is 'already an object named 'Site' in the database.
>       [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE testdb.dbo.Site
>       ("Site_Id" int, "Site_Name" varchar(255), "Type" varchar(5), "Region" 
>       varchar(255))

Comment: try `dbWriteTable(con, "Site", dt1, append = T)`

Comment: Please note: `RODBC` is a different package than `odbc` though both do use ODBC drivers (a technology not limited to R). The package `odbc` complies with R's DBI standard. You appear to be using an `odbc` connection, *con*, in an `RODBC` method, `sqlSave`. Please edit your code as you conflate the two even reflected in first error. And per R tag (hover to see): specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot Julien, that worked! For others, the solution is: dbWriteTable(con, "Site", dt1, append = T)